# Signing and submission of transaction seperately

Tags: eosjs, transactions, eosio.cdt, deferred-transactions

is there any way where we can have a user sign a transaction using their private key on the front end. And we get the signed transaction transfer it to our server over the internet and push the transaction on the blockchain from the server. So we don't have to wait for transaction completion on the front end using eos-js. I don't know if this is a feasible option would really like input on the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do this.  As long as the transaction is signed by the user (on the client side) and is eventually pushed to the blockchain, then it works.  How those 2 events are connnected is up to you.  You must not exceed the expire time of the transaction by taking too long.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply yes i tested this and it works. A follow up question is is it save to transit the signed transaction over the network between my server?